# Homework basic abstract algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

My question is as follows:

$R$ is a ring such that for all $x \in R, x^2=x$

$p$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

Show that $R/p$ (R modulu p) has exactly 2 elements.

What I did:

$x^2=x$

$x^2-x=0$

$x(x-1)=0$

So the equivalence class of $x(x-1)$ is equal to the equivalence class of $0$ in $R/p$ which implies that $x(x-1)$ is an element of $p$

Because $p$ is a prime ideal, we know that this means that either $x \in p$ or $x-1 \in p$...But not both. So why 2 elements? I'd say $R/p$ has exactly one element. But I'm wrong. I could use an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many solutions can $x^2=x$ have in the **integral domain** $R/p$?

Comment: I don't know. I don't understand this material very well. I'd say 2. Either 0 or 1. But not necesarily both

Comment: @Oria: Consider this: in an integral domain, there are *no zero divisors*. What would $x(x-1)=0$ mean if $x$ was neither $0$ nor $1$? (You should also know the fact that if $p$ is a prime ideal then $R/p$ is an integral domain.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff How do we know that $R/p$ is a field? and about the integral domain: I don't know what it would mean. This is the first time I've heard the phrase "integral domain" or that $R/p$ is an integral domain.

Comment: @Oria: Okay... well, you know either $x\in p$ or $x-1\in p$, which means that $x+p$ is one of the cosets $0+p$ or $1+p$. Thus these are the only two elements in $R/p$.

Comment: @OriaGruber I misread. If $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal, $R/\mathfrak p$ is a domain, and conversely. A (commutative) ring is an integral domain iff $ab=0\implies a=0\text{ or } b=0$.

Comment: That makes sense Anon. Thanks, I think I understood.